# Encode french character in Java?

Tags: java, utf-8, smpp, jsmpp

```
How can i encode french Character?

let's say i have String strMEssage='Pour se désinscrire du service ';
String utf8 = new String(strMessage.getBytes("ISO8859_15"),"ISO8859_15");
```

o/P is not proper for special char ? is coming

Comment: Why use that? A `String` is a sequence of characters; just use the `String` as it! Where do you get the data from? Where does the problem appear?

Comment: `String strMessage = "Pour se désinscrire du service";` with double quote not simple quote.

that's all you need ;) it will work. It works with japanese so french is not a problem ;)

Comment: @fge i have to send this String as Message Over SMPP protocol, so as End user the Mesage is not proper

Comment: @CladClad problem here is as End user..End User is not recieving proper message..see above comment

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing a lot of concepts here.

A `String` is a sequence of `char`s. The fact that internally Java uses UTF-16 is irrelevant.

You never send Java `String`s as is, nor receive a Java `String`, nor write `String`s directly in a file, not read `String`s directly from a file. You send/receive *bytes*. And turning bytes into characters and the reverse is made by a `Charset{Decoder,Encoder}`.

In Java source files, just write the string as you want it. When you send/write/receive/read it, use the correct encoding. That is all there is to it.

See [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) for generic information.

And if you use a `Reader` or `Writer`, **always** specify the encoding.

Comment: what kind of Encoding i should use?

Comment: UTF-8, very probably. Use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` in code where a `Charset` is asked for.

Comment: i think i am unable to explain you my problem, i will try to make you understand:

I have a message(French Message) which i am taking from DataBase and Sending to Customer on Phone.|
Now the Communications Protocol is SMPP, so i am Using UCS-2 Encode Formatting.

Comment: Then use UTF-16. It is the same as UCS-2, except that UTF-16 supports Unicode code points above 0xFFFF (which UCS-2 doesn't)

Comment: i used , still issue is same..:(

Comment: (sorry for the language) Bon, on va faire autrement: pose une autre question, mets-y le code que tu utilises actuellement et explique le problème que tu rencontres.

Comment: 'public class Encoding {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketTimeoutException, AlreadyBoundException, VersionException, SMPPProtocolException, UnsupportedOperationException, IOException {
  SubmitSM sm=new SubmitSM();
 String strMessage="Pour se désinscrire du service TT ZONE, envoyez GRATUITEMENT « DTTZ » ";
 String utf8 = new String(strMessage.getBytes("UTF-8"));
 UCS2Encoding uc = UCS2Encoding.getInstance(true);
 sm.setDataCoding(2);
 sm.setMessageText(utf8);
 System.out.println(sm.getMessageText());
 }
}'

Comment: i put that as Que. as title "Encode french character in Java over smpp"